# RMS Current calculation from MCP3008

Tags: circuit-design, analog, adc, rms, jetson

How to find RMS value of current from ADC value gets from CT??? . I have done like below

1. Made a burden resistor and voltage divider circuit for CT
2. MCP3008 connected with Jetson through SPI
   5V  to VDD
   5V to VREF
3. From CT circuit  output connected to ADC0 pin of MCP3008
4. I have plotted the ADC values received , it looks like a sine wave.
5. And i have converted the ADC values to corresponding Voltage
   (adcnum * 5 / 1024 - 2.5 ) *1000.0 /66.0 ;
6. plotted voltage  its in sine wave
7. And for RMS current i have used ( VMax / sqrt(2) ) / calibration_value
   But The problem is when we calibrated RMS current with mains it will not matching when after certain hours or day.

is this equation for RMS current correct ?? and how to cirrect the RMS noise

image attached is ADC plot and CRO wave
[image]

[image]

Comment: "it looks like a sine wave", I don't see any resemblance to a sine wave.

Comment: You can calculate the RMS of any waveform using numerical methods on the series of numbers. First, square the numbers, then take the mean (average) of the square. Then take the square root of the average. Root. Mean. Square.  Vmax/sqrt(2) only works for sine waves, which this is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffFrsm.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

- HPF: High pass FIR filter of 20HZ , used to eliminate DC bias
- X^2 : Squaring each sample
- MAV: Collecting squared sample in a large Moving Average Filter
- SQRT: Calculate square root of the entire MAV

Answer (score 0):

Note: It does not look like a straight sinewave, but there is a noisy sinewave with peaks that might be due to saturation of transformer.

Alternative approach to RMS calculation in time domain: calculation in frequency domain using Fourier (e.g. FFT). It is more complex and the approach by @Marko is preferable if you need only RMS; if you want to play with spectrum, components and so on, instead ....

1. You have the samples coming from the ADC (vector x[n]). Select M the number of points of a single FFT. It depends on the sampling rate and the a priori info on existing sinewave period Tsin that you want to capture; otherwise select a convenient time span T, knowing that the frequency resolution will be df=1/T. Example: for Tsin = 20 ms you get df=50Hz, so you will the harmonics of 50Hz; if you want resolution of 10Hz, then select T=0.1s. Let's go ahead with T and df.
2. X=FFT(x,M). Vector X has X[0] that is the DC component and you can ignore it. Then X[1 ... M/2] is the first half to retain, the second half is symmetric and can be discarded (x[n] is a real signal). X must be "normalized": a) divide X by thee number of points M; b) the amplitude must be multiplied by 2 as you discard the other half and work only on the values in the first half; the DC component should not be multiplied by 2. So, X_new={X[0], 2*X[1...M/2]}
3. Information obtained. a) the spectrum so you see the components that make x[n]; b) you can get the largest component with Xmax=max(abs(X[1...M/s])). b) the bin (frequency value) of the largest component is likely to be the frequency of the fundamental as repetition rate of similar periods (segments inside x[n], e.g. one noisy sine period and its peaky profile).
4. Calculation of RMS:

- You choose if you want the RMS of the fundamental only: rms1 = Xmax/sqrt(2); (note: this time you divide by sqrt(2) one FFT component that is implicitly sinusoidal, you can do it).
- You include the components of the spectrum up to some maximum frequency, and maybe starting from a minimum frequency. This is the total rms. You sum the selected components in quadrature. rms_tot=sqrt( sum(X[k]^2) )/sqrt(2)
  where the sum() is done on the selected components. (note: if you have a periodic signal the best choice above at 1) is selecting T as the implicit period, because you get clearly and only its harmonics, not spectral components that might be unrelated.

5. Problems. Despite frequency analysis with FFT (or similar) is powerful, spectral leakage is  problem. So after this first approach is implemented you should apply "windowing" (aka "tapering") to the sequence x[n] before FFT. Otherwise, e.g. for Hanning window there is an economic way of applying it afterwards on the calculated spectrum X.
   Computational burden. Almost all micro have an optimized FFT function, best if M is  power of 2.